# How to match array with onther array inside an object ? (Js)

Tags: javascript, react-native

begginer developer (JS,ReactNative) .
i want to match an array of ingridients thats passed to the function as a parameter to extricate the recipies thats match .
iv'e tryied diffrent functions like map and filter but without succsess .
i need to use PureJs function .

Example :

```
             Ingridients = ['eggs', 'lemon']   ----->   (Passed as a parameter)

             Recipies = [
                          {
                            _id:1,
                            _recipieName:"Eggs and Lemon",
                            _recipieIngridients:["eggs","lemon"]
                          },
                          {
                            _id:2,
                            _recipieName:"Onther Recipie",
                            _recipieIngridients:["water","bread","blablabla"]
                           }
                         ]

                i need that result-->

                     NewArray = [
                          {
                            _id:1,
                            _recipieName:"Eggs and Lemon",
                            _recipieIngridients:["eggs","lemon"]
                          }
```

Thx.

Comment: Did you intentionally define `Ingredients` as `['eggs,lemon']` (array with a single element) or did you mean to write `['eggs', 'lemon']` (array with 2 elements)? If intended to be 1 element why pass it as an array at all?

Comment: i intended to write with a multiple elemnts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can achieved by doing the following

Exact match:

```js
const matchRecipe = (ingredients) => 
   Recipies
      .filter(r => r._recipieIngridients.length === ingredients.length && r._recipieIngridients.every((ingredient, index) => ingredient === ingredients[index]))
```

Here, I'm filtering the recipies using `filter`, and as a predicate, I'm using `every` to check that each element inside the `_recipieIngridients` matches each element inside `ingredients` by using the `index` that is taken as a second argument from the `every` function

If you don't need it to match the position of the element, you can sort both ingredients so that they should all match whatever the previous order is

A more simplified version without using nested prototype functions:

```js
const matchRecipe = (ingredients) => Recipes.filter(recipe => {
  if (ingredients.length !== recipe._recipieIngridients) return false
  // Sort both if needed
  for (let i = 0; i < recipe._recipieIngridients.length; i++) {
    if (recipe._recipieIngridients[i] !== ingredients[i]) return false
  }
  return false
})
```

Hope you find this helpful

Edit (1)
For your comment, if you want partial matching, you can do the following

```js
const matchRecipe = (ingredients) => 
   Recipies
      .filter(r => r._recipieIngridients.length === ingredients.length && r._recipieIngridients.some((ingredient) => ingredients.include(ingredient)))
```

The prototype function `some` will return true once any of the elements match any of the ingredients by using the `include` function

Comment: Hi , when i use the first example i can only use the Accurate recpie with the exactly same ingridients . if i want to include evrey recpie ? like for example i have [eggs, lemon , cheese] in my ingridients array and i want to get those 2 recipies who have only ["eggs"] in one and ["lemon,"cheese"] at the second and i want both of them recipies what should i do?

Comment: @DavidB, please check the edit on my answer, hopefully that answers your question

Comment: hi man , 
appreciate the help ! unfortunately i dont get any recipies at all in my array now. (the first example works fine)

Answer (score 0):

You should try something like that:

```
const availableReciepes = Recipies.reduce((result, reciepe)=>{
    let hasAllIngredients = Ingridients.reduce((carry, ingredient)=>{
        if(!reciepe.ingredient) 
            return false;
        return carry;
    }, true);

    if(hasAllIngredients){
        result.push(reciepe);
    }

    return result;
}, []);
```

Basically, for every recipe, check if you have all the ingredients, then adds it to the reduce carry.

Comment: tnx man thats great !!

Comment: No worries, hope tha helped ! Think about checking the answer that helped the most to mark the question as solved ;)

Comment: Typo: `returnn false;`

Answer (score 0):

You can put the ingredients into [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) to compare them efficiently, for example

```
const recipies = [
  {
    _id:1,
    _recipieName:"Eggs and Lemon",
    _recipieIngridients:["eggs","lemon"]
  },
  {
    _id:2,
    _recipieName:"Onther Recipie",
    _recipieIngridients:["water","bread","blablabla"]
  },
  {
    _id:3,
    _recipieName:"Eggs with Cheese Recipie",
    _recipieIngridients:["eggs", "cheese"]
  } 
];

function filterByIngridients(recipies, ingridients, howMatch = 'every') {
  const set = new Set(ingridients);
  return recipies.filter((r) => {
    return r._recipieIngridients[howMatch]((r) => set.has(r));
  });
}
```

Now you can match every ingredient

```
let output = filterByIngridients(recipies, ['eggs', 'lemon']);
console.log(output);
```

Output:

```
[
  {
    _id: 1,
    _recipieName: 'Eggs and Lemon',
    _recipieIngridients: [ 'eggs', 'lemon' ]
  }
]
```

Or some ingredients

```
output = filterByIngridients(recipies, ['eggs', 'lemon'], 'some');
console.log(output);
```

Output:

```
[
  {
    _id: 1,
    _recipieName: 'Eggs and Lemon',
    _recipieIngridients: [ 'eggs', 'lemon' ]
  },
  {
    _id: 2,
    _recipieName: 'Eggs with Cheese Recipie',
    _recipieIngridients: [ 'eggs', 'cheese' ]
  }
]
```

Comment: first of all thanx a lot ! if i want to include evrey recpie ? like for example i have [eggs, lemon , cheese] in my ingridients array and i want to get those 2 recipies who have only ["eggs"] in one and ["lemon,"cheese"] at the second

Comment: @DavidB if I correctly understand you, you can achieve this with "some": `filterByIngridients(recipies, ['eggs', 'lemon'], 'some');`. Try it if you haven't done it already and let me know. If you think I don't understand, update your question with the input and the expected output values.